# console.log object/function properties in Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Logging a function/class

[image]

or a flat object/array

[image]

results in logging a string representation (with no dropdown ► icon).

Logging complex objects (with own non-scalar properties) results in having hierarchical representation:

[image]

I would prefer to have the latter behaviour for all logged objects - both  things that are typed in console and things that are logged with `console.log`.

For this reason only Firebug console output looks much more beneficial than Chrome dev tools.

I'm aware of `console.dir`, though it is inefficient to type `console.dir(someVar)` instead of `someVar` in console, and it is not appropriate to replace all `console.log` occurrences with `console.dir` in existing apps.

Other `console` methods (`console.warn`, `console.error`) have the same problem as `console.log`, but they don't have `console.dir` counterpart for them!

Can this Chrome dev tools behaviour be changed? Is there something that can help with this problem?

Comment: As a guess - you might override the normal `console` object and it's functions. Personally, I won't really consider this that big of a problem to throw more than few minutes of effort into it and that seems like too much to really bother with. It _might_ be that there is a library that replaces the vanilla `console` but I've not really sought one out.

Comment: FYI: You don't need to type `console.dir(someVar)`, you can just type `dir(someVar)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would generally just use `dir(myObj)` if you just want something quick. i don't think it's much effort to replace your log statements.

However, you could look into [Custom Object Formatters in Chrome DevTools](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FTascZXT9cxfetuPRT2eXPQKXui4nWFivUnS_335T3U/preview). You need to enable this feature in the DevTools settings and then implement the `window.devtoolsFormatters` object with the header and (optional) body you would like.

Depending on the type of object passed in, you can provide a different formatter for each. For example, you can check if the object is an array with `Array.isArray(myObj)` and then you can traverse the array properties and expose and format the ones you feel are relevant as the return object for the body.

You would need to run this as a snippet each time, or create a Chrome Extension to automatically inject this when you run your application.