# Properties of element cant see in the browser console

Tags: javascript, html

I can't check the button element property in the browser console window. The triangle is missing is there any one know how to get it pls. Here i have attached an image with printed element and object. For object it shows option.But to the element its not

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [console.log object/function properties in Chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260250/console-log-object-function-properties-in-chrome-dev-tools)

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: Use `console.dir` instead? You want to _expand an HTML element logged in the console_. “Triangle is missing” is focussing way too much on an insignificant symptom rather than the root cause or the actual goal.